# In Powershell script file residing in TFS, how to read SQL File which resides in TFS?

Tags: sql, powershell, visual-studio-2012, tfs, continuous-deployment

I am maintaining my Powershell script file and SQL file in TFS repository.  I am trying to ready my SQL file from Powershell script (which is also residing in TFS).  I am calling this powershell script in my build.  I am getting error when I execute.

```
$ServerInstance = "ABCServer"
$Database = "MyDB"
$ConnectionTimeout = 30
$Query = get-content "$/MYPROJECT/Queries/GetProjects.sql"
$QueryTimeout = 120

$conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
$ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f     $ServerInstance,$Database,$ConnectionTimeout
$conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString
$conn.Open()
$cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn)
$cmd.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout
$ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
$da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
[void]$da.fill($ds)
$ds.Tables[0] | foreach {
    write-host 'Name value is : ' + $_.Title
}
$conn.Close()
#$ds.Tables
```

My Powershell is saved in "$/MYPROJECT/PowershellScripts/QueryDB.ps1"

I have this Powershell added as TFS task in my Build steps.  I am getting the following error

```
**PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand 
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot open database "MyDB" requested by the login**
```

Comment: Looks like the TFS part is being run under different an account and it lacks permissions to the database. Check the Sql Server's log for failed logon attempt.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

In the build process it will first get the source (.sql file) to Agent machine. It works with the variable `"$env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH/Queries/GetProjects.sql"` set when run the PS script on Agent machine.

If you need to run the PS script on **other** machines (not the agent machine), You have to copy the script file to that machine first, and specify the actual file path in the script.

---

I can reproduce your issue, please following below steps to fix it:

1. Modify `GetProjects.sql` file path in your PowerShell script based
   on your project structure like this:(See screenshot example)

   `$Query = get-content "$env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH/Queries/GetProjects.sql"`

So, the complete PS script should be :

```
$ServerInstance = "ABCServer"
$Database = "MyDB"
$ConnectionTimeout = 30
$Query = get-content "$env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH/Queries/GetProjects.sql"
$QueryTimeout = 120

$conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
$ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f     $ServerInstance,$Database,$ConnectionTimeout
$conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString
$conn.Open()
$cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn)
$cmd.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout
$ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
$da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
[void]$da.fill($ds)
$ds.Tables[0] | foreach {
    write-host 'Name value is : ' + $_.Title
}
$conn.Close()
#$ds.Tables
```

2. Add build agent **service account** (the default service account
   should be **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE** if you didn't change it)
   as the database ("MyDB") users with the login and query permissions.
3. Go to **Database** >> **Security** >> **Users** and right click on
   **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE** and select **Properties**
4. In newly opened screen of Login Properties, go to the
   “**Membership**” tab. On the lower screen, check the role
   **db_owner**. Click OK.

Then try building again, it should works now.

[image]

Comment: @Barani Have you resolved your issue by above workaround? any update for this?

Comment: Thank you Andy.  It didn't solve the problem.  Actually the powershell script was target to different machine.  It seems the actual file is being expected in that local machine and not as environmental variable.  For PS in target machine, we need to provide actual path.  As the file is executed in target machines, I used SQL's relative path and able to achieve it.

Comment: @Barani I updated the answer, Actually in the build process it will first get the source (.sql file) to Agent machine. It worked well at my side with the variable  "$env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH/Queries/GetProjects.sql" set. If you mean you need to run the PS script on other machines (not the agent machine), of cause you have to copy the script to that machine first, and specify the actual path in the script.